# Open Tab in a Specific Position by Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-bootstrap, firefox-addon-overlay

Say, there are 10 tabs in Firefox browser window.

How can I add a tab in after 2nd tab by a Firefox extension code?

`gBrowser.addTab` method only appends to the tab list.

Comment: From the looks of the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Method/addTab), I don't think you can. `addTab` only allows for `URL`, `referrerURI`, `charset`, `postData`, `owner` and `allowThirdPartyFixup` as parameters, none of which seem to affect the location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy, *direct* way of doing what you want. If you *really* want to open a tab *directly* at a specific index then you can take a look at the [code for](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/tabbrowser.xml#1795) [`gBrowser.addTab()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Method/addTab) and the [code for](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/tabbrowser.xml#2897) [`gBrowser.moveTabTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Method/moveTabTo); copy them and modify them to do what you want. Note that this code is in an XML representation of JavaScript. Thus, you will need to reformat it a bit if you want to use it.

However, the *easy* way to do this is to open the tab, `gBrowser.addTab()`.  Then, move it to the index that you desire, `gBrowser.moveTabTo()`.

The following code will do what you want. When I attached this code to a button, the tab visually appeared to open at the index specified. It did *not* open first at the end of the tabs and then appear to move. There was no user noticeable difference between doing this, adding then moving, instead of *actually* adding the tab at the specified index.

```
function handleButtonCommandEvent(event) {
    let window = event.view;

    //Create the window variable if it does not exist. It should
    //  already be defined from event.view.
    //  This should work from any Firefox context.
    if (typeof window === "undefined") {
        //If there is no window defined, get the most recent.
        var window=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                             .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                             .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
    }

    //Test addTabAtIndex()
    addTabAtIndexInWindow(window, 2, "http://www.ebay.com/")
}

/**
 * Open a tab in specified window at index.
 */
function addTabAtIndexInWindow(window, index, URL, referrerURI, charset, postData,
                       owner, allowThirdPartyFixup ) {

    //Get the  gBrowser for the specified window
    let winGBrowser = window.gBrowser;

    //Open a new tab:
    let newTab = winGBrowser.addTab(URL, referrerURI, charset, postData,
                                    owner, allowThirdPartyFixup );
    //Immediately move it to the index desired:
    winGBrowser.moveTabTo(newTab,index);

}
```

Comment: @JohnSewell, I updated the code to have a generic function for adding a tab at index in a specified window.

Comment: looks great. Thank you.